# How to get not existing records as null from total records?

Tags: mysql, sql

Table1: **tbl_users**:

```
+----+--------+
| id | name   |
+----+--------+
| 1  | waheed |
+----+--------+
| 2  | fareed |
+----+--------+
```

Table2: **tbl_watched**:

```
+------------+----+--------+
| id_watched | id | name   |
+------------+----+--------+
| 1          | 2  | fareed |
+------------+----+--------+
```

I want to get the total records if the tbl_watched is not present it should return as `zero` or `null`

Output:

```
+----+--------+--------+
| id | name   |watched |
+----+--------+--------+
| 1  | waheed |  90    |
+----+--------+--------+
| 2  | fareed |  null  |
+----+--------+--------+
```

How can I get this kind of result?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use LEFT JOIN

```
Select t1.id , t1.name, count(*) as total from tbl_users as t1 
left join tbl_watched as t2 on t1.id=t2.id_watched
group by t1.id , t1.name
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do that with a `LEFT JOIN` between `users` and `watched`. That will preserve all rows in the left table and will assign `NULL` if no matching record is available on the right side. On this result set you can `GROUP BY` the user's name and count how many things each one has seen.

```
select  t1.name, count(t2.id)
from    tbl_users t1
left join
        tbl_watched t2
on      t1.id = t2.watched_id
group by t1.name
```

Answer (score 1):

You can join the tables. I'm not sure about the `id_watched` column there, assuming its a foreign key from another table. Created a sample schema and query for you at SqlFiddle. Please notice that the third person does not have any watched content, so the count will be 0 in this case. See [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/02005a/2).

Sample Schema:

```
create table tbl_users (
  id INT(8) UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  name VARCHAR(266) NOT NULL
);

create table tbl_movies (
  id INT(8) UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  name VARCHAR(266) NOT NULL
);

create table tbl_watched (
  id INT(8) UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  user_id int(8) UNSIGNED,
  movie_id int(8) UNSIGNED,
  FOREIGN KEY (user_id) REFERENCES tbl_users(id),
  FOREIGN KEY (movie_id) REFERENCES tbl_movies(id)
);

INSERT INTO tbl_users (name) VALUES 
("John Doe"),("Jane Doe"),("Jamie Fox");

INSERT INTO tbl_movies (name) VALUES 
("The Pianist"),("Django Unchained"),("Pulp Fiction"),("Wanted");

INSERT INTO tbl_watched (user_id,movie_id) VALUES 
(1,1),(1,2),(1,3),(2,3),(2,4);
```

Sample query:

```
SELECT u.*
     , COUNT(w.id) watched_count 
  FROM tbl_watched w
 RIGHT 
  JOIN tbl_users u
    ON u.id = w.user_id
 GROUP  
    BY u.id;
```

Comment: As of this second, a quick search for "RIGHT JOIN" under the [mysql] tag on Stack Overflow returns 985 results. Contrast that with the 11,190 results returned for "LEFT JOIN". My point is that RIGHT JOINs are vanishingly rare. Just sayin'. ;-)